# C# replace not working correctly replacing this/that

Tags: c#

I have an issue with the replace in C#.

```
string replacementForError = "<span id='" + idError + "' class='" + typeError[typeWordInError - 1] + "' oncontextmenu='rightClickMustWork(event, this);return false'>" + wordToReplace + "</span>";
paragraphe[i].InnerHtml = paragraphe[i].InnerHtml.Replace(wordToReplace , replacementForError);
```

what the sample of code do is : when a word in error is find, he replace it with himself surround by a span for identification.

it work perfectly for these kind of error :

```
This(e) become <span ...>This</span>(e).
```

But do not work for these kind of error :

```
Veuf/veuve
```

For this one both of the word are in error but we get them separated and the result should be :

```
<span...>Veuf</span>/<span...>veuve</span>
```

For this case "this" and "that" should be replace with the span around(both replacement are done one after another in a for loop based on the list of word in error).

Is it because of the way replace judge from the start and end of the word I am trying to replace ? (in this case why does it work with a "(" and not with a "/") ?

Edit : `paragraphe[I].InnerHtml` before the replace `<p><font>Veuf/veuve</font></p>`

Value of the list wordToReplace => wordToReplace = {"Veuf","veuve"};

Comment: Is this webforms or mvc?

Comment: "/" means to escape the next character, unless you preface the string with a "@".

Comment: In the second case of `this/that`, what is the exact value used for `wordToReplace`?

Comment: @Gnqz it netheir of them, is pure C# using HTMLAgilty pack

Comment: @mellamokb the exact value is this and that (these value are in a list and each string in that list is corresponding to a word in error). The / is not a part of the word in error that's why he is not inside the span.

Comment: @RicGaudet the "/" isn't part of the replace statement, he is just a char inside the global string where I replace some string inside.

Comment: @Slayner: So if I understand correctly, the code literally is doing this: `paragraphe[i].InnerHtml.Replace("this and that", replacementForError);`  In that case, then it is clear why it is not matching.  Otherwise, can you clarify **exactly** what is being passed in for the second example?

Comment: @mellamokb sorry my bad if I confused you, the code is executed 2 times : once for this and a seconde time for that; so it is 'Replace("this", replacementForError);' and the seconde execution 'Replace("that", replacementForError);' I'll edit the question for more clarification.

Comment: @Slayner: gotcha, that makes more sense now :)  I just tested it according to your code example, and it works as expected: **http://ideone.com/gXV0yc**.  So some other detail must still be missing.  Is it possible that the `wordToReplace` is also part of the `span` text?  For example, if the error is `oncontextmenu`, it would cause confusion because it would also replace parts of previous `span`.

Comment: @mellamokb well in the same text sample I got 146 word in error, and the only case where there is a fail is this one and I don't know why, my guess was that because of the "/" the word bondarie defined by Replace struggle with it.

Comment: @Slayner: I don't think we'll be able to help without a [complete, self-contained demonstrated example](http://sscce.org/).  I think it would help if you could provide two things.  First, the exact HTML code in `paragraphe[i].InnerHtml` for the example that's not working.  Second, the exact list of values being passed into `wordToReplace` for the sample that's not working.  Also, it is complicated by the fact that this is not just a normal string, you are using `HtmlAgility` document with `InnerHtml`, which may be altering how the string works for `Replace`.

Comment: I'll ad the detail you asked for, for the part with the HTMLAgilityPack, sadly if it is because of this, I would not be able to correct this.

Comment: @Slayner: Are `this` and `that` the *real* values or placeholders?  It's still working fine in my sample code, so I think you're not providing the real thing.  Unfortunately the problem may not show itself except with the actual, live data you are working with.

Comment: @mellamokb real value are french words i'll put them in place of this and that.

Comment: @Slayner: I don't know.. I'm out of ideas at this point :/.  I tested in LINQPad using the exact values you provided, and downloaded the HTMLAgility pack and used it to create a document sample.  It is replacing both words just fine with two spans.  There's got to be some detail that's missing to make your example behave differently.  **Edit**: Here's the sample code I'm using to test with: http://pastebin.com/c2vUBHCh.  I can't demo it with online code hosting because it relies on a 3rd-party dll HtmlAgility.

Comment: @mellamokb thanks for trying mate, I don't know why for this one it fail and not for the 144 other word in error maybe by adding some trim everywhere it will work (maybe a space get in the string somehow). If I try to correct it i'll post the answer.